# www and HTTPS Rules Web Config

Tags: azure, web, https, rules

How can add HTTPS and WWW Rules in web config. 
Regarding Azure cloud Website.

Please describes how to write rules for HTTPS and WWW Everywhere, a browser extension that switches sites over from HTTP to HTTPS and www automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can force redirection of HTTP to HTTPS foe your ASP.NET Azure Web App by following this example Web.Config (copied from [this Azure documentation page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#4-enforce-https-on-your-app)):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Regarding your question on WWW Rules, if you mean setting up a custom domain name and configuring DNS records for your app, these can be achieved by using Azure Traffic Manager. More details can be found here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name/